# Deploying play framework on weblogic

Tags: java, servlets, playframework, websocket, playframework-2.1

How can I deploy a play 2.1 web application to oracle weblogic 10.3?

Weblogic is running on windows server 2008 r2.

My application has web socket and I undersand that there are problems with them on deployment.

**Edit:**

I understand that servlet 3.0 does not support web sockets. If so, what does Play run on its own server?

Comment: Great question! I have the same question...

Answer (score 6):

Play isn't a Java EE framework. It doesn't use servlets and doesn't natively deploy to an application server. Instead, it brings its own full stack. You just run your application standalone, without any external application server. *(It's quite common to put your Play application behind a load balancing webserver, but that's not the point right now.)*

While there [exists a plugin that lets you bundle up your Play application into a war](https://github.com/dlecan/play2-war-plugin), I'm not sure it'll do much good in your case. It's not tested on WebLogic. Also, and that's the more fundamental problem: if I'm not mistaken, WebLogic 10.3 [only supports servlet specification 2.5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_WebLogic_Server#Standards_support_by_version), while [Websockets are only available starting with servlet 3.1](https://blogs.oracle.com/arungupta/entry/what_s_new_in_servlet). So what you're planning won't work, regardless of Play.

**Edit:**

Regarding your edit: There still seems to be a misconception here. Play is *not* a Java EE framework. It does *not* use servlets. It does *not* package its application up as wars, and it does *not* need an application server for deployment. Play comes with its own webserver, which is based on [Netty](http://netty.io/). This built-in webserver supports Websockets and all of Plays features.

And I checked the source of the [play2-war-plugin](https://github.com/dlecan/play2-war-plugin), and it looks like [Servlet 3.1 is not (yet) supported](https://github.com/dlecan/play2-war-plugin/blob/develop/project-code/plugin/src/main/scala/Play2WarSettings.scala#L30). [Same goes for Websockets](https://github.com/dlecan/play2-war-plugin/blob/b3871ec6c564c3740c4a3f9f30b6875c75b656d8/project-code/core/common/src/main/scala/RequestHandler.scala#L372).

To summarize: No, at this moment, it is **not** possible to write a Play 2 application that uses Websockets and deploy it to a servlet 3.1 container.

Comment: So if im obligated to using weblogic am i best off not using play? Do i have better java web framework options for what im looking for?

Comment: No. What I am trying to tell you is, that WebLogic 10.3 *does not* support Websockets at all. They're only [introduced in the newest version, 12.1.2](http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/wls/NOTES/index.html#CJABIGIC). This has nothing to do with Play.

Comment: So if i update weblogic to the newest version i will have no problem with play?

Answer (score 1):

In play1.x, we can package the project to a war, by using `play war`however Play 2.x doesn't allow that. You could use external plugins  https://github.com/dlecan/play2-war-plugin to package your apps into standard WAR packages from Play framework 2.

Comment: Problem with this solution is that I'm pretty sure web sockets are not supported when deploying this way...